# Debugging With PM2 And Vscode

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, pm2

Visual Studio code has some awesome debug functionality built in that makes it easy to debug applications with node. However, my application is configured to use PM2 version 3.4.1. node version 6.17.1
How can I set up Visual Studio Code to debug with PM2?

Answer (score 9):

Vs code has a debugging option called “Attach” which allows you to attach to a running Node.js program, 
A sample configuration would be

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach",
      "port": 9229
}
```

Now you need to start your Node.js program like below

```
$ pm2 start "My App" --node-args="--inspect-brk" --watch
```

vs code docs : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations

Comment: I have .yaml file loaded by too many microservices. Then? Like                           
apps:
- name: account
  script: app.js
  out_file: /dev/null
  error_file: /dev/null
  cwd: ../sk_account
  env:
    UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE: 12
    PUTTU_IP: 127.0.0.1
    REDIS_CON: localhost:6379
    ES_URL: localhost:9200
    MONGO_URL: mongodb://
    XAMPP_URL: 
    HOST_NAME: localhost
    CONFIG_URL: ../config/globals.js
- name: apigateway so on...

Comment: can anyone reply on this!

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant here, please check out this link for further details on how to attach process to vs code debugger. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attach-to-node-process-action

Answer (score -3):

Its possible to debug one of the micro-service from the list by stopping it like "**sudo pm2 stop sk_account**"

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
  {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/sk_account/app.js"
   }

]
```

Here "**sk_account**" is my micro-service name Form the list.

Comment: But This is not the solution for the above question.