# Vscode debugger - auto-attach when process restarts through pm2

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, pm2, vscode-debugger, node-inspector

I am experimenting with different environments for debugging a nodejs application.  I am running this application using `pm2`, with the `--watch` flag, so that my application restarts when files are changed / saved.  Relevant scripts are these:

```
"start": "node --inspect -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/server.ts",
"launch": "pm2 start pm2.config.js",
```

And my pm2.config.js looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'myapp',
            script: 'npm',
            args: 'start',
            watch: ['src'],
        },
    ],
};
```

So far, I have been doing debugging in the chrome node inspector.  I'm also using the chrome extension [NodeJS Inspector Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en), which is a nice wrapper for the node inspector.  It has a nice UI, and you can see there are options for Auto Attach and Auto Resume:

[image]

With these enabled, any time I save files in my project, pm2 will restart the application.  NiMs automatically detaches and reattaches to the running application, and I have an interactive chrome inspector debugging environment that refreshes through application restart.

I'd like to reproduce this effect within the vscode debugger.  I can manually start a debug session that attaches to my application running through pm2.  With some help from [Debugging With PM2 And Vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57002100/debugging-with-pm2-and-vscode), I'm able to direct the vscode debugger to attach to my application running through pm2.  However, when I save files, pm2 restarts the process, and vscode debugger detaches, but does not reattach.

NiMs has a [vscode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=June07.nims&utm_source=NiM&utm_medium=options%20page&utm_campaign=nims&utm_content=1), though it doesn't seem to offer the same functionality within vscode as within chrome, as far as I can tell.

Is there a way to set up a vscode debugger to attach to a pm2 process, and automatically restart as the process restarts (on the same debugger port)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have vscode debugger re-attach automatically, you can add the flag `restart` to your configuration:

```
{
  "name": "Attach to node",
  "type": "node",
  "request": "attach",
  "restart": true,
  "port": 9229
}
```

source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_restarting-debug-sessions-automatically-when-source-is-edited

Comment: So simple. Thank you, this works!

Comment: i searched a long tie for exactly this answer and came acress so many complicated solutions. thank you very much

Comment: alternatively you could use "Auto Attach" built into vsc. doest even need a launch.json file and restarts with the updated code every time you save something to the file.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_auto-attach